How to change recurrence in Gmail attachment to Google Drive Workflow
I'm using Save Gmail attachments to your Google Drive workflow. I tried to send multiple emails, but the workflow only triggered in test mode. I checked the code and I found this:
"recurrence": {
        "interval": 15,
        "frequency": "Minute"
    }

Turns out there's a huge delay between triggers. Is there any way to change it, since code can't be edited? or an alternative?

Peek Code:


If you click on the recurrence action, you can edit the interval and frequency of when the flow is triggered under the parameters tab


There is no recurrence action. The "When an email arrives" trigger has this code, and it triggers every 15 mins.

I also updated my question at the same time @iBeMeltin. Also updated Question with pictures.
